# How do you simultaneously solve two ore more equations in two fields (or extensions)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory, prime-numbers, roots

How do you formally extend the two fields $\Bbb{Z}/p$ and $\Bbb{Z}/q$ at the same time?

In other words, I have two polynomials:

$$
f(X) = 0 \pmod p \\
g(X) = 0 \pmod q
$$

and I'm looking for a solution $X$ that satisfies both equations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot find a **field** that extends both $\mathbb Z/p$ and $\mathbb Z/q$ for $p\neq q$. This is because we can exploit that $p,q$ are coprime and find integers $a,b$ such that $ap+bq = 1$ so that in the "common extension" field, $1=0$.

That being said, you can work in $\mathbb Z/pq$ which is a ring that has maps to both $\mathbb Z/p$ and $\mathbb Z/q$ and find a common solution here using the [chinese remainder theorem (CRT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem#Computation).

More details: You'd solve the individual equations in parallel in $\mathbb Z/p$ and $\mathbb Z/q$ (using quadratic, cubic, quartic reciprocity or whatever other method) first. Say there are $k_1$ and $k_2$ solutions to the two equations in $\mathbb Z/p$ and $\mathbb Z/q$  respectively. Then by CRT, you will have $k_1k_2$ solutions in $\mathbb Z/pq$.

Comment: Why does the GCD = 1 imply that $1 = 0$?

Comment: Say there is a common field $F$ containing both. In this $F$, we have to have $p=0$ and $q=0$ (because these equations are true in it's subfields!). Therefore $ap+bq = 0$ as well and therefore $1=0$ and $F$ is the trivial ring.